# SO_PEERCRED vs SCM_CREDENTIALS - why there are both of them?

Tags: linux, credentials, unix-socket

SO_PEERCRED is simple way to get pid/uid/gid of connected AF_UNIX stream socket, SCM_CREDENTIALS is more or less the same, but more complex (various ancillary messages). [Links to example showing both ways](http://man7.org/tlpi/code/online/dist/sockets/scm_cred_recv.c.html).

1. Why there are two ways to get more or less the same information?
2. Why the more comfortable SO_PEERCRED is not listed in unix(7) manpage?
3. Which is use more in real-life applicatins?

What should I use?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

1. If I understand correctly, there is a subtle difference between the two. `SO_PEERCRED` retrieves the credentials of the peer process, without requiring any interaction from the peer process. In contrast, `SCM_CREDENTIALS` is a mechanism to send / receive credentials of the peer process, which are then checked by the kernel. This subtle difference may matter when a process is running as UID 0. `SCM_CREDENTIALS` allows a process running as UID 0, to declare itself less privileged (e.g., UID 50), whereas this would not be possible with `SO_PEERCRED`.
2. See above. I guess using `SCM_CREDENTIALS` is encouraged and `SO_PEERCRED` is only supported for compatibility.
3. The dbus daemon seems to use `SO_PEERCRED` and `getpeereid()`. I think it is best to copy their code in order to portably get the credentials.

http://cgit.freedesktop.org/dbus/dbus/tree/dbus/dbus-sysdeps-unix.c?id=edaa6fe253782dda959d78396b43e9fd71ea77e3

Comment: There's another subtle difference.  SO_PEERCRED gives you the credentials of the process that *created* the socket at the other end.  The process that created the socket can later drop privileges, setuid, setgid, etc. and your SO_PEERCRED results will remain unchanged.

Comment: To further clarify @jtchitty's comment - *created* would mean the time peer called *connect* (and not *socket*).

Comment: It's also worth noting that you'll only get valid data in `SCM_CREDENTIALS` after at least one end of the socket has turned on `SO_PASSCRED`. If you turn on `SO_PASSCRED`, and then try to receive a message that was sent before hand, you'll receive an `SCM_CREDENTIALS` control message with invalid values (pid = 0, uid/gid = -1).

Answer (score 5):

`SO_PEERCRED` returns the socket peer's credentials. `SCM_CREDENTIALS` allows you to pass any credentials which you have privilege over. This is particularly valuable because the kernel will translate the ids, so a task in one pid namespace can send a pid to process in another namespace, and be assured that the received pid will refer to the same process it intended.

If you want the peer's credential then use `SO_PEERCRED`. `SCM_CREDENTIAL` is a credential which the caller specified (which it did have to have privilege over), not necessarily the peer's.